# npm error : 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-whitelist

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I have installed a cordova-plugin-whitelist in Visual Studio project with cordova from [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git) but when I recompile, I get this error:

```
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.1-dev"
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.1-dev" via plugin registry
MDAVSCLI : npm error : 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

All files of plugin there are  correctly under plugin folder of my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible answers:

1. use 'clear cordova cache' in visual studio options - tools - tools for apache cordova.  then recompile.  during recompile, make sure you have internet access.
2. some versions of cordova Api in github simply can't be used in visual studio cordova, try newer or older version.  once a version works, do not change to another version if not necessary.
3. If you are using Visual Studio 2013 Community Update 4 with Cordova Ctp3.1 or any older version, try to install Visual Studio 2015 Community RC and select cordova during the installation, some api problems disappear in vs 2015.  btw, vs 2013 and 2015 can co-exist, however, do not open the old cordova project in vs 2015, create a new project and put everything inside old index.html in new index.html, because these 2 html are not in the same root directory, of course, you need to add Api again in the new project.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors of this question, I had the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083504/cordova-plugin-whitelist-error-404-not-found), and as it seems, from an [official blog post](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html), Cordova is moving their plugins to npm.

I installed the [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist) easily now with npm:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Comment: I think it should be `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35303570/3565153

The short version is to use the git repo

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist
```