# cordova-plugin-whitelist Error 404 not found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to run this code:
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` but what I keep getting is this:

`Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" via plugin registry
Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-whitelist
    at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:304:14)
    at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:246:65)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:236:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1142:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1096:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an [official blog post](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html), Cordova is moving their plugins to npm.

I installed the [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist) easily now with npm:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Comment: I think it should be `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

Comment: @A1rPun no, it shouldn't be that. that is exactly the reason for the post. `cordova plugin add` goes to cordova.io which is 404 for the plugins. Hence why it has to be installed with NPM.

Comment: @SMT In the "official blog post" they say you need to update cordova to 5.0.0 to use the new ID's. `npm install` did not work for me but updating cordova did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add on an additional answer:

In Visual Studios (VS2015 at least) you can open the config.xml in designer mode (or Shift + F7 to open it) and go to Plugins -> Custom and then give the git repo URL to install a plugin that way to have it be available to the project you're working on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today, and basically I needed the plugin, but it isn't maintained on http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Thankfully, cordova can resolve git repos I just used that instead

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist
```